# What is the performance impact of rendering a larger quad?

Tags: unity, textures, performance, blender, uv-mapping

Lets say I have two planes and I textured them in blender with a `512*512` tiled texture. One plane is bigger than the other (for example, one plane tiles the texture 60 times but another only six times). I've import the planes in to Unity and assign that same `512*512` texture to them.

What is the difference in performance in-game? Because both of those objects use one draw call and same `512*512` texture, therefore same texture space, so what is the difference in performance?

[image][image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the only difference between the quads is their physical size in window coordinates ("one is bigger than the other on-screen"), and all other things (shader, textures, et cetera) are equal, then the only significant difference in the pipeline will be that the rasterizer must fill more fragments for the quad that is larger on-screen.

This means that if the fragment shader being used is expensive, the larger quad may be more expensive in terms of fillrate.

It is, however, unlikely that this is going to create a noticeable performance differential, especially in the shaders you are *likely* to be using to simply paint a quad with a texture.

While there are a few other potential avenues for performance issues, they depend on factors that you having elaborated on. With only the information you've provided, fillrate is going to be the only technical difference, and even that won't likely be measurable.